# Zeta-function of $x_0^3 + x_1^3 + x_2^3 = 0$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Tags: finite-fields, zeta-functions

Consider the projective curve over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_4$
$$C/\mathbb{F}_4\colon x_0^3 + x_1^3 + x_2^3 = 0.$$

Let's calculate the zeta function
$$Z (C/\mathbb{F}_q) = \exp \left(\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\# C (\mathbb{F}_{q^n})\,t^n}{n}\right)$$
(where $q = 4$ in this case).

I see two ways of doing that, but neither is elementary.

1. The curve is smooth of degree $3$, so its genus is $1$, and in this case the zeta function depends only on $\# C (\mathbb{F}_q)$: it is given by
   $$Z (C/\mathbb{F}_q) = \frac{1 - at + qt^2}{(1-t)\,(1-qt)}, \quad a = 1 + q - \# C (\mathbb{F}_q)$$
   (see e.g. [Silverman, GTM 106, Section V.2]). It is easy to count that $\# C (\mathbb{F}_4) = 9$, and therefore
   $$Z (C/\mathbb{F}_4) = \frac{(1 + 2t)^2}{(1-t)\,(1-4t)}.$$
2. Alternatively, for any hypersurface of the form $x_0^m + x_1^m + \cdots + x_n^m = 0$ there is a formula in terms of Gauss sums (see e.g. [Ireland-Rosen, GTM 84, Section 11.3]), which in this case boils down to
   $$Z (C/\mathbb{F}_4) = \frac{P (t)}{(1-t)\,(1-4t)},$$
   where
   $$P (t) = \left(1 + \frac{1}{4}\,g (\chi_1)^3\,t\right)\,\left(1 + \frac{1}{4}\,g (\chi_2)^3\,t\right),$$
   and $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are the nontrivial characters $\mathbb{F}_4^\times \to \mathbb{C}$. A little calculation gives $P (t) = (1+2t)^2$, as expected.

However, once we have the zeta function, we see that the number of points is given by a rather easy formula:

\begin{align*}
\# C (\mathbb{F}_4) & = 9 = (2+1)^2,\\
\# C (\mathbb{F}_{4^2}) & = 9 = (2^2-1)^2,\\
\# C (\mathbb{F}_{4^3}) & = 81 = (2^3+1)^2,\\
\# C (\mathbb{F}_{4^4}) & = 225 = (2^4-1)^2,\\
\# C (\mathbb{F}_{4^5}) & = 1089 = (2^5+1)^2,\\
\# C (\mathbb{F}_{4^6}) & = 3969 = (2^6-1)^2,\\
 & \cdots
\end{align*}

So my question is:

> could anybody give an elementary counting argument explaining this?

Comment: The elementary derivation is given in Ireland & Rosen, what do you expect more ?

Comment: $C$ is also an elliptic curve. The data heavily suggests that the group of $\Bbb{F}_{4^n}$-rational points is a full torsion group of the obvious exponent. I vaguely recall having done that exact calculation once (to the version of this curve in its Weierstrass form), but I'm not sure we would call that *an elementary counting argument* either. Even though (IIRC) we get away with the point doubling formula alone. I guess you want one that simply counts the solutions. Without character sums and Hasse-Davenport?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Well, "character sums and Hasse-Davenport" is what I mention in part 2.

Comment: Quite. Sorry about being obtuse :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen If you have a nice solution with the Weierstrass form, I'd be happy to see it :-)

Comment: Those old notes are in my office. I probably need to reproduce the calculation. Looks like that will have to wait.

Comment: May be we can use the fact that the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{4^m}$ is a direct product of two cyclic subgroups, one of order $2^m-1$, the other of order $2^m+1$. They can be viewed as the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ and the kernel of the relative norm map $N:\Bbb{F}_{4^m}\to\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ respectively. Exactly one of the factors has order divisible by three, so cubing is a bijection on the other. I don't see it yet, but I will try that first. But, missus wants me to do some chores, and its volleyball night :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some facts about elliptic curves it could go as follows.

Let's look at the cubic projective curve given by the equation
$$
X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0.
$$
Putting this into Weierstrass form is easy. All we need to do is to substitute $Z=Y+U$, and (recalling that we are in characteristic two) we get
$$
X^3+U^3+U^2Y+UY^2=0.
$$
If we dehomogenize $x=X/U,y=Y/U$, we get an equation in the Weierstrass form
$$
E:x^3+1=y^2+y.\qquad(*)
$$
The above process maps $\Bbb{F}_{4^m}$-rational points to each other bijectively, so we might as well count the number of points $\#E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})$.

The curve $E$ has a very special form. If $P=(x_0,y_0)\in E$, then the negative of this point (= the other point on the same vertical line) is $[-1]P=(x_0,y_0+1)$.
Furthermore, implicit differentiation tells us that the tangent of $E$ at $P$ has slope $x_0^2$. The usual process then leads to the very simple point doubling formula
$$
[2](x_0,y_0)=(x_0^4,y_0^4+1).\qquad(**)
$$
In other words doubling can be achieved by applying the square of the Frobenius followed by negation.

If $(x_0,y_0)\in E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})$ then repeated application of $(**)$ tells us that
$$
[2^m](x_0,y_0)=(x_0^{4^m},y_0^{4^m}+m\cdot1)=
\begin{cases}P,&\ \text{if $m$ is even, and}\\
[-1]P,&\ \text{if $m$ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$

> This means that all the points $P$ of $E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})$ satisfy the equation $[M]P=0$ for $M=2^m-(-1)^m$.

With a few basic facts about elliptic curves in place this implies that
$$E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})=E[M],\qquad(**)$$
and thus has $M^2$ points. More precisely, the highlighted result tells that we have an inclusion "$\subseteq$" in $(**)$, so $\#E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})$ must be a factor of $M^2$. But then the Hasse-Weil bound $|\#E(\Bbb{F}_{4^m})-(4^m+1)|\le2\cdot 2^m$ rules out all proper factors.

---

I'm afraid this is unsatisfactory as an answer here. Hasse-Weil bound was needed to conclude, and that is at the same depth as the use of Zeta functions. I posted it chiefly, because I discussed an argument related to elliptic curve in the comments.
The calculation I recalled must have been about another elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Sorry. Anyway, this does lead to the conclusion, but overall the method is kludgier than those listed in the question.

Comment: I like this approach, and I am going to accept this answer. It explains where the points come from and I think it's okay to bring Hasse-Weil, because my initial explanation simply quotes the general calculation for an arbitrary elliptic curve.

Comment: @AAA93 I think we can actually use the elliptic curve $x^3+1=y^2+y$ to get an exact count. Excluding the point at infinity, this has $N_m=4^m+S(m)$ points with  $$S(m)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{4^m}}\chi(x^3+1),$$ where $\chi(u)=(-1)^{tr(u)}$ is the canonical additive character. The point is that it is possible to calculate the absolute value of this sum by a squaring trick (like Gauss sums). You don't need the Weil bound at all. Ok, so it still uses character sums, but only the elementary theory. Should have recalled that right away!

Answer (score 2):

The idea in my latter comment (under main) leads to a "pure" counting argument. Unfortunately only in the case of an odd value of $m$. I abbreviate $q=2^m$.

Because we think projectively we can normalize the first non-zero homogeneous
coordinate of $[x_0:x_1:x_2]$ to be equal to one.

Let us first look at the points with one of the coordinates equal to zero.
The field $E=\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ contains a primitive third root of unity $\omega$. If we for example assume that $x_0=0, x_1=1$, we see that $x_2$ must be a power of $\omega$. This shows that the projective curve has exactly nine points with the property that one coordinate vanishes, namely the cyclic shifts of $[0:1:1]$, $[0:1:\omega]$ and
$[0:1:\omega^2]$. For the rest of this post we consider the points with all the 
homogeneous coordinates $\neq0$. In other words, we want to count the number of solutions
of
$$
x_1^3+x_2^3=1\tag{1}
$$
with $x_1,x_2\in E^*$.

The multiplicative group $E^*$ is cyclic of order $q^2-1=(q-1)(q+1)$. As $\gcd(q-1,q+1)=1$ we can split it into a direct product
$$
E^*=F^*\times S,
$$
where $F=\Bbb{F}_{q}$ is the unique subfield such that $[E:F]=2$, and $S$ is the
kernel of the relative norm map $N_{E/F}:x\mapsto x^{q+1}$.

If we assume that $2\nmid m$, then $3\nmid 2^m-1=q-1$ implying that cubing permutes the elements of $F^*$. Another key observation is that if $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ are two distinct elements of $S$, then their ratio is not in $F$, and hence $\{\eta_1,\eta_2\}$
is an $F$-basis of $E$. Observe that $3\mid 2^m+1$ implying that $\omega\in S$.

Anyway, we can uniquely write $x_i=y_i\eta_i$ with $y_i\in F^*$, $\eta_i\in S$. Plugging these in $(1)$ gives the equation $y_1^3\eta_1^3+y_2^3\eta_2^3=1$. Because cubing permutes the set of available $y$-components, and we are only in the interested in the number of solutions, we can equally well replace $y_i^3$ with $y_i$. So we want the number of solutions of
$$
y_1\eta_1^3+y_2\eta_2^3=1.\tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, cubing is a 3-to-1 mapping on $S$. This allows us to count the number of solutions of $(2)$:

- Assume first that $\eta_1^3\neq1$. This holds for all choices of $\eta_1$ except powers of $\omega$, so there are $q+1-3=q-2$ choices for $\eta_1$. Assume further that $\eta_2^3\notin\{1,\eta_1^3\}$. To a fixed $\eta_1$ this leaves $q+1-6=q-5$ choices for $\eta_2$. Anyway, in this main case $\eta_1^3$ and $\eta_2^3$ for a basis of $E$ over $F$. Therefore $(2)$ has a unique solution $(y_1,y_2)\in F^2$. Here both $y_1,y_2$ are necessarily non-zero. For if, say $y_1=0$, then $(2)$ implies that $y_2\eta_2^3=1$ implying that $\eta_2^3\in F^*$ and thus forcing $\eta_2^3=1$ contradicting the choices we made.
- If $\eta_1^3\neq\eta_2^3$ but exactly one of these cubes happens to equal to $1$, then the argument from the last line of the preceding bullet shows that one of $y_1,y_2$ vanishes, and we get no new solutions to $(2)$.
- On the other hand in the case $\eta_1^3=1=\eta_2^3$ (three choices for both $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$, so a total of nine combinations), the equation $(2)$ becomes
  $$y_1+y_2=1.$$ As we prescribed $y_1$ and $y_2$ to both be non-zero, this equation holds for $q-2$ pairs $(y_1,y_2)$ in the field $F$.

The conclusion is thus that $(2)$ has
$$
(q-2)(q-5)+9(q-2)=q^2+2q-8
$$
solutions. Adding the nine points with a single vanishing homogeneous coordinate we see that
$$
\#C(E)=q^2+2q-8+9=(q+1)^2
$$
verifying the answer gotten by more high-powered methods.

---

Unfortunately I couldn't make this argument work in the case $2\mid m$ on either of first two attempts. This time cubing is no longer bijective in $F^*$. It is bijective in $S$, but the analogue of $(2)$:
$$
y_1^3\eta_1+y_2^3\eta_2=1\tag{2'}
$$
is not as easy to analyze:

- Using linear dependence of $\mathcal{B}=\{\eta_1,\eta_2\}$ when applicable is not straight forward for it is difficult to analyze the occasions where the coordinates of $1$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ should be cubes in $F$.
- There is the further observation that in the special case $\eta_1=1=\eta_2$ the equation $(2')$ becomes $(1)$, but with the variables ranging over the smaller field $F$. This is not a problem per se, as we can use induction on $m$ to handle those points. However, it also implies that the number of solutions of the type $\eta_1\neq1, \eta_2\neq1$ will depend on the residue class of $m$ modulo four. I didn't spot a way forward reflecting this.
- An alternative (initially my main line of attack) would be to use $(2')$ to solve one of the $\eta_i$s (the equation is linear!). All the elements of $S$ satisfy the equation $\eta^q=\eta^{-1}$. Together with $y_i^q=y_i$ an application of the Frobenius shows that the solution $\eta_2$ of $(2')$ is an element of $S$ if and only if the solutions (=the choices of $\eta_1$) of the quadratic
  $$
  \eta^2+\frac{1+y_1^6+y_2^6}{y_1^3}+1=0
  $$
  are not elements of $F$ (when they will necessarily be in $S$). This leads to a trace condition, and it looks like the number of solutions can only be countes with the aid of a character sum, which is something I wanted to avoid.

Anyway, if I come up with another way of handling $(2')$, I will edit this. Apologies for failing to deliver.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much for your work, I find this very instructive.

Comment: Actually, this example is an exercise in Ireland and Rosen, Chapter 11. They ask to do the calculations over $\mathbb{F}_4$, and the intended solution most likely involves character sums. But then they ask to do it again directly over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and the only hint they give is that every element is a cube in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for odd $n$ (this case is indeed easy), and that $3$ divides $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}^\times$ for even $n$. So presumably, they have in mind some simple argument for the latter case, but I couldn't find it either...